# For loops are skipped, why?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have an assignment in which i have to create a console program in c++ that draws Hexagons in a given style. The problem i am having is; my For loops are never entered and i can't figure out why. here's the snippet of code I'm having trouble with.

```
    void display()
{
    int counter=0;//var that keeps track of the layer that is being drawn
    for(int i=0;i>=size;i++)//spaces before first layer of hexagon
    {
        cout<<" ";
    }
    for (int k=0; k>size;k++)//top layer of hexagon
    {
        cout<<"_";
    }
    cout<<endl;//ends the first layer
    for (counter; counter>=size-1;counter++)//outer loop for the top half that controls the size
    {
        for( int j=0;j>(size-counter);j++)//adds spaces before the shape
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"/";
        for( int p=0; p>(size+(counter*2));p++)//loop for the hexagon fill
        {
            cout<<fill;
        }
        cout<<"\\"<<endl;
    }
    for(counter;counter==0;counter--);  //loop for bottom half of the hexagon
    {
        for( int j=0;j>(size-counter);j++)//adds spaces before the shape
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\\";
        for( int p=0; p>(size+(counter*2));p++)//loop for the hexagon fill
        {
            cout<<fill;
        }
        cout<<"/"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\\";
    for(int r=0; r>=size;r++){cout<<"_";}
    cout<<"/"<<endl;

}
```

the 'Size' and 'fill' are selceted earlier in the program during my main()
I'm probably missing something very simple but I've been struggling with this for a while. Any help would be greatly appricated!

Comment: You have all of your tests reversed. `for(A; B; C){D}` is roughly equivalent to `A; while(B) { D; C; }`.

Comment: what is size? is it negative value?

Comment: yeah look like i jsut had my test reversed, thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is the content of your `size` variable but it looks like you have got your loop conditions wrong:

```
for(int i=0;i>=size;i++)
```

probably should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
```

The same goes for other loops.

Comment: Careful(!): `i<=size` is not the same as `!(i>=size)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your loops use `>` and start at 0. It seems you want `<` instead. For example

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)//spaces before first layer of hexagon
{
    cout<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `size` is a postive number, it works as per your condition.
Change the `>` conditojs to `<` in your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In your conditions, invert the > to <

< means inferior, you want to do a

```
for i = 0; if i < size; i++
```

You do

```
for i = 0 ; if i > size ; i ++
```

if size is superior to i (0) the loop will never trigger

Answer (score 1):

Aren't all of your < and > reversed? Because

```
(int k=0; k>size;k++)
```

makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think the problem lies deeper, in the understanding of the condition. To the asker, it (probably) makes sense, because he/she reads `for xxx until condition`

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops in C++ are *while* loops, not *until* loops.

C++ has only *while* loops (with the meaning of *as long as*):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    ....


int i=0;   
while (i<10) {
    ....
    ++i;
}
```